# jQuery -webkit-transform yAngle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Just as a learning experience, I am trying to make en element rotate on its yAxis upon clicking a link, but I am having no luck. Here is the code I am using. Any ideas?

```
$('rotate').click(function(){

$('object').style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(90deg)";});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not how you apply CSS styles with jQuery. [This is](http://api.jquery.com/css).

```
$('rotate').click(function ()
{
    $('object').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(90deg)');
    // or this:
    // $('object').attr('style', '-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg)');
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to use .animate with this? It is animated as is, but I'd like to know if i could speed up the animation or slow it down.

Comment: @mcbeav: as far as I know, it is only possible to animate _numeric_ CSS properties, using strictly vanilla jQuery - though [there is a plugin for that™](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html). Ssee [the `.animate()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more - you could pretty easily write your own code to repeatedly increase the rotation amount, though.

Comment: @mcbeav: no problemo. That's what the Stack Exchange inbox is good for :)

Answer (score 4):

`.style` isn't a jQuery object property, if you wanted to affect one, use `[0]` like this:

```
$('.rotate').click(function(){
  $('.object')[0].style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(90deg)";
});
```

Or, to affect all of them use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('.rotate').click(function(){
  $('.object').each(function() {
    this.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(90deg)";
  });
});
```

Note that your selectors `'rotate'` and `'object'` are looking for `<rotate>` and `<object>` elements...so you'll want to adjust those selectors accordingly, above I'm looking for `class="rotate"` for the click, etc.

An alternative more jQuery-ish way (debatable for custom properties) is [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), like this:

```
$('.rotate').click(function(){
  $('.object').css("webkitTransform", "rotateY(180deg)");
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/cFU5h/).

Answer (score 0):

The QTransform jQuery plugin extends jQuery's css to include setting css Transforms. You can write:
    $('object').rotate('30deg'); 
    or animate with 
    $('object').animate({rotate:'+=30deg', 1000});

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/QTransform